# Setting NSURLSessionConfiguration's HTTPShouldSetCookies to false disables cookie storage

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

What I want to do is create an `NSURLSession` that does not automatically give a value to the `Cookie` HTTP header when I'm making an `NSMutableURLRequest`, because I set that value on my own. However, I want to be able to store the cookie that comes back to me when I make a sign in API request.

I use the following code to instantiate my session:

```
func createSession() {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    // Set cookie policies.
    configuration.HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = .Always
    configuration.HTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    configuration.HTTPShouldSetCookies = false

    // ...

    return NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
}
```

When the `NSURLSessionDataTask` comes back to me in its `completionHandler`, I dig into the shared cookie storage to get the cookies that came with the response. However, I always get an empty array.

```
if let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookiesForURL(response.URL!) {
    println("cookies: \(cookies)") // Prints an empty array.
    if let cookie = cookies.last as? NSHTTPCookie {
        // I save the cookie to disk here.
    }
}
```

Why is this happening even when I've set the `NSURLSession` to always accept cookies, and even provided a cookie storage?

I can only get the behavior that I want by setting the `HTTPShouldSetCookies` to `true` and supplying a `Cookie` HTTP header in my `NSMutableURLRequest` anyway. However, the Apple documentation on `HTTPShouldSetCookies` says that I should set it to `false` if I were to provide the cookie on my own in the request level:

> If you want to provide cookies yourself, set this value to NO and provide a Cookie header either through the session’s HTTPAdditionalHeaders property or on a per-request level using a custom NSURLRequest object.